# How to Speed Up the Visualization of This 3d Graphics?

Tags: graphics3d

I want to visualize the following graphics:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[t x] == Sin[t y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

It takes long time before the results come out, and, when I rotate the 3d graphics, it moves quite slowly.

What measures can I take to speed up the calculation, as well as a smoother rotation? (I don't need high fidelity 3d graphics).

Thanks.

Comment: Look up the following options (within the `ContourPlot3D` doc page): `PerformanceGoal`, `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your advice, I found that `PlotPoints` will improve the precision of the 3d graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the value of the option [`PerformanceGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html) to `"Speed"`:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[t x] == Sin[t y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[t x] == Sin[t y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Default value of the option is `"Quality"`:

```
Options[ContourPlot3D, PerformanceGoal]
```

> {PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal}

```
$PerformanceGoal
```

> "Quality"

Comment: thanks for your advice. I got the point.